# why am I getting error when try to use JMapper in java spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to use JMapper in my spring boot application.

these are my model:

```
public class TodoItemDto {
    private Integer id; 
    
    private String title;
    
    private String description;
   
    private Boolean isDone; 
    //getter & setters
   }

@Entity
public class TodoItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id; 

    private String title; 

    private String description; 
     
    private Boolean isDone; 

    private Date createdAt; 

    private Date doneAt;
    //getter & setter
}
```

and I am configuring my mapper this way:

```
Optional<TodoItem> result = todoRepository.findById(id);
JMapperAPI mapperss = new JMapperAPI()
        .add(new MappedClass(TodoItemDto.class)
            .add(new Attribute("id").value("id"))
            .add(new Attribute("title").value("title")) 
            .add(new Attribute("description").value("description"))
            .add(new Attribute("isDone").value("isDone"))
        );
        
        JMapper<TodoItemDto, TodoItem> mapper = new JMapper(TodoItemDto.class, TodoItem.class, mapperss);
        
        var res = mapper.getDestination(result);
```

But when I am running my code this exception will be thrown:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: com.googlecode.jmapper.exceptions.JMapperException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause

java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @6b81ce95
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:40) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:832) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:496) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:465) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:411) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:350) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
        at com.googlecode.jmapper.util.FilesManager.toXmlJmapper(FilesManager.java:1047) ~[jmapper-core-1.6.1.CR1.jar:na]
        at com.googlecode.jmapper.util.FilesManager.readAtRuntime(FilesManager.java:1036) ~[jmapper-core-1.6.1.CR1.jar:na]
        at com.googlecode.jmapper.xml.XML.<init>(XML.java:66) ~[jmapper-core-1.6.1.CR1.jar:na]
        at com.googlecode.jmapper.xml.XmlBuilder.atRuntime(XmlBuilder.java:44) ~[jmapper-core-1.6.1.CR1.jar:na]
        at com.googlecode.jmapper.generation.MapperBuilder.generate(MapperBuilder.java:84) ~[jmapper-core-1.6.1.CR1.jar:na]
        at com.googlecode.jmapper.JMapper.createMapper(JMapper.java:450) ~[jmapper-core-1.6.1.CR1.jar:na]
        at com.googlecode.jmapper.JMapper.<init>(JMapper.java:432) ~[jmapper-core-1.6.1.CR1.jar:na]
        at com.googlecode.jmapper.JMapper.<init>(JMapper.java:412) ~[jmapper-core-1.6.1.CR1.jar:na]
        at com.googlecode.jmapper.JMapper.<init>(JMapper.java:386) ~[jmapper-core-1.6.1.CR1.jar:na]
        at com.example.todo.controllers.TodoController.getTodoItam(TodoController.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:537) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:an]
```

I am using java version 17

Comment: same error here :(

Comment: I changed my mapping to **MapStrutc** and it was working like a charm :(

Comment: Could you post your code as answer and solve this topic?

Comment: you can find my code here: https://github.com/shokri-navid/spring-boot-learning/tree/master/todo/ @Guilherme Bigois

Comment: export JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS=’ — add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED — add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED — add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED — add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED’